# AttributeError: 'SQLiteCursorWrapper' object has no attribute 'callproc'

Tags: python, django

In my Django Application, I started using SQLite in an app heavily developed under MySQL. I actually swapped to SQLite because I was having issues with MySQL. However, the most important thing is to make this work so I can submit my task, but the error I am getting is `AttributeError: 'SQLiteCursorWrapper' object has no attribute 'callproc'`. Bellow is my settings in settings.py.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your settings but in your code somewhere, you must be calling `callproc ` method of cursor object, which is used for calling a stored procedure on MySQL. So you need to find that and adept it to SQLLite somehow.

Comment: But really you should have looked into solving your "issues with MySQL", rather than randomly switching to a different - and less powerful - database.